# Magento 2 add custom shipping cost to order

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

How can i add custom shipping cost to the order

here is the code.

```
     $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
     $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
```

Comment: Reference Free Plugin => https://github.com/magepal/magento2-custom-shipping-rate

Comment: Ya i am using that but how can i apply it using the code?

Comment: Are you asking to automatically apply shipping to a quote (basket) or add it to an order as part of a programmatic order generation process?